# Shopify Carrier Service not picking up rates from JSON response

Tags: ruby, json, api, shopify

I can't get Shopify to pick up my shipping rates. I'm not getting any errors, but the shop also isn't getting the rates I'm rendering. I've correctly setup a Carrier Service, and verified its existence. I'm able to then receive requests at my URL, and I prep my rates and render a JSON response in less than 1 second. Just my rates never display. I've verified all the fields in my JSON response and I don't see anything. Any ideas?

My routes look like this:

```
post '/webhook/carrier', to: 'webhook#carrier'
get '/webhook/carrier', to: 'webhook#carrier'
```

I just render my JSON like this:

```
render json: @shopify_response
```

And then the actual JSON is below:

```
{
"rates": [
    {
        "service_name": "Standard",
        "service_code": "FU",
        "total_price": "875",
        "currency": "USD",
        "min_delivery_date": "2016-03-11 08:00:00 +0000",
        "max_delivery_date": "2016-03-16 06:59:59 +0000"
    },
    {
        "service_name": "Priority",
        "service_code": "FU",
        "total_price": "2075",
        "currency": "USD",
        "min_delivery_date": "2016-03-08 08:00:00 +0000",
        "max_delivery_date": "2016-03-09 07:59:59 +0000"
    },
    {
        "service_name": "Expedited",
        "service_code": "FU",
        "total_price": "1195",
        "currency": "USD",
        "min_delivery_date": "2016-03-10 08:00:00 +0000",
        "max_delivery_date": "2016-03-11 07:59:59 +0000"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your return looks fine except your dates are not ISO strings.

e.g. instead of

```
2016-03-10 08:00:00 +0000
```

you should be sending

```
2016-03-10T00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: yea I saw that too.. tried both formats, and they both didn't work.. I think its HOW I'm sending the response.. I have the carrier service setup in Shopify as XML. They send XML to me, but I send back JSON.. but that is what they show on the Carrier Service API page.. Nicely stuck

Comment: What content-type header are you sending? I just set mine to text/javascript and it worked fine.

Comment: never mind. the json: method should do that.(know nothing about Ruby). However in the samples I just looked up they'd expect `render :json => @shopify_response`

Comment: yea its the same as what I have.. but I have that crazy header I can't seem to get rid of.. the header looks like: {"X-Frame-Options"=>"SAMEORIGIN", "X-XSS-Protection"=>"1; mode=block", "X-Content-Type-Options"=>"nosniff"}

Comment: Did you send my JSON to Shopify?!?! That would help a bunch, then I would know its the way I'm sending and not the what..

Comment: No. Sorry I don't have a Carrier Service set up with my current Dev account. When I wrote about my content-type header I was referring to a Carrier Service that is in operation.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is correct. Change date

2016-03-10 08:00:00 +0000

to

2016-03-10T00:00:00.000Z

and ShopFy acept.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).